# Merging 2 datasets with multiple variables (Cannot use just similar variables)

Tags: python, mysql, matlab, sas, weka

I am trying to merge 2 datasets (150,000 and 50,000 records) which have around 50 variables each, some of which might match. One common variable in both the datasets is the 'Incident date' but I cannot use that, as the datasets have like 300 incidents that took place on that particular date (broken down by address, city, county, zip, time emergency medical services (EMS) was notified). The other data set has the exact time the incident took place, address, city, county, zip and some other fields but these fields maybe blank if the information is not known/recorded.

I would like to create a buffer to join the datasets by each field. For example, first starting with the date of the incident(no missing values), if they are the same, next step would be to check if they took place in the same county, city and so on. (some values might be blank). Final field for comparison would be when EMS was notified (upto 30 - 60 minutes after the incident). If all fields match, then it comes down to this final buffer of 30 - 60 minutes. It would be a many to one merge(50,000 to 150,000).

What program would let me do this? Is there a certain code?

I have added a snippet of both the datasets (https://filedropper.com/filemanager/public.php?service=files&t=0f2d129b1622901fafc8c9e678433623&download) and (https://filedropper.com/filemanager/public.php?service=files&t=642c840bc3e431c3d4d839a71bb66944&download)

[image: datasets]

Expected output looks something like this

[image: expected output]

Code used was:

```
T1 = readtable('dataset1.csv')
T2 = readtable('dataset2.csv')
LT1 = size(T1,1);
LT2 = size(T2,1);
T1 = [T1, cell2table(repmat({''}, LT1, 7),'VariableNames', {'County_Name', 'City_Name', 'Town_Name','CrashTime', 'SecondaryLocation', 'RouteName', 'PostalCityName'})]
augmented = false(LT1,1);
dtstr = 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm';
trange = duration([0,0,0;1,0,0]);
for tt2 = 1:LT2
cdate2 = T2.CrashDate{tt2};
crasht2 = T2.CrashDateTime{tt2};
assert(~isempty(cdate2) & ~isempty(crasht2),'Major data missing')
crashdt2 = [cdate2, ' ', crasht2];
crashdt2 = datetime(crashdt2,'InputFormat',dtstr);
strtaddr2 = T2.RouteName{tt2};
if ~isempty(strtaddr2)
strtaddr2 = upper(strtaddr2);
strtaddr2 = strrep(strtaddr2,'ROAD','RD');
strtaddr2 = strtaddr2(isletter(strtaddr2));
end
pcityn2 = T2.PostalCityName{tt2};
if ~isempty(pcityn2)
pcityn2 = upper(pcityn2);
pcityn2 = pcityn2(isletter(pcityn2));
end
countyn2 = T2.County_Name{tt2};
if ~isempty(countyn2)
countyn2 = countyn2(isletter(countyn2));
countyn2 = upper(countyn2);
countyn2 = strrep(countyn2,'COUNTY','');
end
for tt1 = 1:LT1
if augmented(tt1)
continue
end
matchvec = true(5,1);
cdate1 = T1.IncidentDate{tt1};
matchvec(1) = strcmp(cdate1, cdate2);
strtaddr1 = upper(T1.AddressStreet{tt1});
if ~isempty(strtaddr2) && ~isempty(strtaddr1)
strtaddr1 = strrep(strtaddr1,'ROAD','RD');
strtaddr1 = strtaddr1(isletter(strtaddr1));
matchvec(2) = strcmp(strtaddr1,strtaddr2);
end
pcityn1 = upper(T1.AddressCityIncident{tt1});
pcityn1 = pcityn1(isletter(pcityn1));
if ~isempty(pcityn2) && ~isempty(pcityn1)
pcityn1 = pcityn1(isletter(pcityn1));
matchvec(3) = strcmp(pcityn1,pcityn2);
end
countyn1 = upper(T1.AddressCountyIncident{tt1});
countyn1 = countyn1(isletter(countyn1));
if ~isempty(countyn2) && ~isempty(countyn1)
countyn1 = countyn1(isletter(countyn1));
matchvec(4) = strcmp(countyn1,countyn2);
end
crashdt1u = T1.UnitNotified{tt1};
crashdt1d = T1.Date12_DispatchNotified{tt1};
if ~isempty(crashdt1u) || ~isempty(crashdt1d)
tmatch = true(2,1);
if ~isempty(crashdt1u)
crashdt1u = datetime(crashdt1u,'InputFormat',dtstr);
difcrdt1d = crashdt1d-crashdt2;
tmatch = difcrdt1d >= trange(1) && difcrdt1d <= trange(2);
end
matchvec(5) = all(tmatch);
end
if all(matchvec)
T1{tt1,{'County_Name', 'City_Name', 'Town_Name','CrashTime', 'SecondaryLocation', 'RouteName','PostalCityName'}} = table2cell( T2(tt2,{'County_Name', 'City_Name','Town_Name', 'CrashTime', 'SecondaryLocation','RouteName', 'PostalCityName'}) );
augmented(tt1)=true;
else
T1(tt1,:)
T2(tt2,:)
matchvec
end
end
end
T1
```

Comment: Suggest you include some sample data (10-20 records) from the datasets you want to merge, and the desired output

Comment: Any variety of SQL should be sufficient.

Comment: If you have names, then Link King would be a good way to do some of the fuzzy matching. There are some alternatives that check across different variables and do a probabilistic match. There are options, but it's not a simple straightforward problem that a single query may answer, multiple SQL joins will help you to get there as well.

Comment: I added a snippet of data to my post. As you can see there, the second last row of the second dataset matches exactly with the 5th row of my first dataset. The last row of my second dataset matches with the 6th row of my first dataset. (time buffer of 3 minutes). Like these, I have to merge 50,000 records from dataset 1 to 150,000 records of dataset 2.

Comment: @Reeza Link king looks like a good tool but it requires a base SAS license. I am using a university edition SAS which is completely online, so I do not have an sas exe file to install link king. Any alternatives?

Comment: The code for link king is available without the exe and then you can run in SAS UE.

Comment: @Reeza Can you provide me with the link? I have been reading about link king, it says that some form of last name and first name should be there in the data which I do not have. Will it still work?

Comment: show what have you done till now to solve the problem :|

Comment: @darenshan Till now, I have just used excel and ArcGIS. but it is not efficient and it is very time consuming and not accurate.

Comment: @Yvon In dataset1, incident date is the only field which is not empty throughout. of 50,000 records, address street has 10 blank and unit notified field has 13 blank. but, the neighboring times can be used in that case(dispatch notified). In dataset 2, crash date and crash time fields are not empty throughout. Out of the 150,000 records there are just 7 missing values in both route name and postal city name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Optimized code for performance; anticipating large amount of data.

Note to OP: Your raw data has many bugs. Commas should not be allowed anywhere in the actual data in the csv file. Some string (found 1 unit notified time) does not have predefined format. The `try` block deals with one particular case;  if all fields are subject to defective data then `try` should be implemented in all fields. All these should be addressed prior to merging.

```
clear;clc;close all

T1 = readtable('dataset1.csv');
T2 = readtable('dataset2.csv');
T1 = T1(1:1000,:);
T2 = T2(1:900,:);
LT1 = size(T1,1);
LT2 = size(T2,1);
% expand T1 for expansion
T1 = [T1, cell2table(repmat({''}, LT1, 7), ....
    'VariableNames', {'County_Name', 'City_Name', 'Town_Name', ....
    'CrashTime', 'SecondaryLocation', 'RouteName', 'PostalCityName'})];

augmented = false(LT1,1); % see usage below
dtstr = 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm';
trange = duration([-1,0,0;1,0,0]); % 0 to 1 hour
strtaddrcmpf = @(c1,c2) cellfun(@(s2) ....
    cellfun(@(s1) ....
    ~(isempty(strfind(s1,s2)) | isempty(strfind(s2,s1))), ....
    c1), ....
    c2);
% buffer original to speed up
fprintf('Pre-processing started at %s \n', datestr(datetime('now')))
T1B = cell2table([repmat({''}, LT1, 5), repmat({true}, LT1, 4)], ....
    'VariableNames', {'CrashDTU','CrashDTD',  ....
    'StrtAdd','PoCityN', 'CountyN', ....
    'CrashDTFlg', 'StrtAddFlg', 'PoCityNFlg', 'CountyNFlg'});
T2B = cell2table([repmat({''}, LT2, 4), repmat({true}, LT2, 3)], ....
    'VariableNames', {'CrashDT', 'StrtAdd', 'PoCityN', 'CountyN', ....
    'StrtAddFlg', 'PoCityNFlg', 'CountyNFlg'});

fprintf('Progress:        ')
for tt2 = 1:LT2
    fprintf('%s',repmat(sprintf('\b'),1,length('Progress:        ')))
    fprintf('Progress: %6.2f%%', tt2/LT2*50);

    cdate2 = T2.CrashDate{tt2};
    crasht2 = T2.CrashTime{tt2};
    assert(~isempty(cdate2) & ~isempty(crasht2),'Major data missing')
    crashdt2 = [cdate2, ' ', crasht2];
    T2B.CrashDT{tt2} = datetime(crashdt2,'InputFormat',dtstr);

    strtaddr2 = T2.RouteName{tt2};
    if ~isempty(strtaddr2)
        strtaddr2 = upper(strtaddr2);
        strtaddr2 = strrep(strtaddr2,'ROAD','RD'); % repeat for HWY ST etc
        strtaddr2 = strsplit(strtaddr2,'/');
        switch true
            case strfind(strtaddr2,'I95')
                strtaddr2 = {'I95'};
            case strfind(strtaddr2,'I495')
                strtaddr2 = {'I495'};
            otherwise
                strtaddr2 = cellfun(@(s) s(isletter(s)), ....
                    strtaddr2, 'Uniform',false);
        end
        T2B.StrtAdd{tt2} = strtaddr2;
    else
        T2B.StrtAddFlg(tt2) = false;
    end

    pcityn2 = T2.PostalCityName{tt2};
    if ~isempty(pcityn2)
        pcityn2 = upper(pcityn2);
        pcityn2 = pcityn2(isletter(pcityn2));
        T2B.PoCityN{tt2} = pcityn2;
    else
        T2B.PoCityNFlg(tt2) = false;
    end

    countyn2 = T2.County_Name{tt2};
    if ~isempty(countyn2)
        countyn2 = upper(countyn2);
        countyn2 = countyn2(isletter(countyn2));
        countyn2 = strrep(countyn2,'COUNTY','');
        T2B.CountyN{tt2} = countyn2;
    else
        T2B.CountyNFlg(tt2) = false;
    end
end
for tt1 = 1:LT1
    fprintf('%s',repmat(sprintf('\b'),1,length('Progress:        ')))
    fprintf('Progress: %6.2f%%', tt1/LT1*50+50);

    strtaddr1 = upper(T1.AddressStreet{tt1});
    if ~isempty(strtaddr1)
        strtaddr1 = strrep(strtaddr1,'ROAD','RD');
        strtaddr1 = strsplit(strtaddr1,'/');
        switch true
            case strfind(strtaddr1,'I95')
                strtaddr1 = {'I95'};
            case strfind(strtaddr1,'I495')
                strtaddr1 = {'I495'};
            otherwise
                strtaddr1 = cellfun(@(s) s(isletter(s)), ....
                    strtaddr1, 'Uniform',false);
        end
        T1B.StrtAdd{tt1} = strtaddr1;
    else
        T1B.StrtAddFlg(tt1) = false;
    end

    pcityn1 = upper(T1.AddressCityIncident{tt1});
    if ~isempty(pcityn1)
        pcityn1 = pcityn1(isletter(pcityn1));
        T1B.PoCityN{tt1} = pcityn1;
    else
        T1B.PoCityNFlg(tt1) = false;
    end

    countyn1 = upper(T1.AddressCountyIncident{tt1});
    if ~isempty(countyn1)
        countyn1 = countyn1(isletter(countyn1));
        countyn1 = strrep(countyn1,'COUNTY','');
        T1B.CountyN{tt1} = countyn1;
    else
        T1B.CountyNFlg(tt1) = false;
    end

    crashdt1u = T1.UnitNotified{tt1};
    crashdt1d = T1.DispatchNotified{tt1};
    if ~isempty(crashdt1u) || ~isempty(crashdt1d)
        tmatch = true(2,1);
%         a little dirty here, need both date and time
        try
            if ~isempty(crashdt1u)
                crashdt1u = datetime(crashdt1u,'InputFormat',dtstr);
                T1B.CrashDTU{tt1} = crashdt1u;
            end
            if ~isempty(crashdt1d)
                crashdt1d = datetime(crashdt1d,'InputFormat',dtstr);
                T1B.CrashDTD{tt1} = crashdt1d;
            end
        catch
            T1B.CrashDTFlg(tt1) = false;
        end
    else
        T1B.CrashDTFlg(tt1) = false;
    end
end
fprintf('%s',repmat(sprintf('\b'),1,length('Progress:        ')))
fprintf('Pre-processing finished at %s \n', ....
    datestr(datetime('now')))

fprintf('Matching started at %s \n', datestr(datetime('now')))

% process data
fprintf('Progress:        ')
for tt2 = 1:LT2
    fprintf('%s',repmat(sprintf('\b'),1,length('Progress:        ')))
    fprintf('Progress: %6.2f%%', tt2/LT2*100);
%     extract a row for comparison
    crashdt2 = T2B.CrashDT{tt2};
    strtaddr2 = T2B.StrtAdd{tt2};
    pcityn2 = T2B.PoCityN{tt2};
    countyn2 = T2B.CountyN{tt2};

    for tt1 = 1:LT1
        if augmented(tt1) % match already found, skip
            continue
        end

%         Boolean comparison: treat missing data as identical
        cdate1 = T1.IncidentDate{tt1};
        match1 = strcmp(cdate1, cdate2); % incident date
        if ~match1
            continue
        end

        if T2B.StrtAddFlg(tt2) && T1B.StrtAddFlg(tt1) % put 2 first: faster
            strtaddr1 = T1B.StrtAdd{tt1};
            strtaddr_cmp = strtaddrcmpf(strtaddr2,strtaddr1);
            match2 = any(strtaddr_cmp); % street name match
        end
        if ~match2
            continue
        end

        if T2B.PoCityNFlg(tt2) && T1B.PoCityNFlg(tt1)
            pcityn1 = T1B.PoCityN{tt1};
            match3 = strcmp(pcityn1,pcityn2); % postal city name match
        end
        if ~match3
            continue
        end

        if T2B.CountyNFlg(tt2) && T1B.CountyNFlg(tt1)
            countyn1 = T1B.CountyN{tt1};
            countyn1 = countyn1(isletter(countyn1));
            countyn1 = strrep(countyn1,'COUNTY','');
            match4 = strcmp(countyn1,countyn2); % county name match
        end
        if ~match4
            continue
        end

        if T1B.CrashDTFlg(tt1)
            crashdt1u = T1B.CrashDTU{tt1};
            crashdt1d = T1B.CrashDTD{tt1};
%             a little dirty here, need both date and time
            if ~isempty(crashdt1u)
                difcrdt1u = crashdt1u-crashdt2;
                tmatch1 = difcrdt1u >= trange(1) && difcrdt1u <= trange(2);
            end
            if ~isempty(crashdt1d)
                difcrdt1d = crashdt1d-crashdt2;
                tmatch2 = difcrdt1d >= trange(1) && difcrdt1d <= trange(2);
            end
            match5 = tmatch1 & tmatch2;
        end
        if ~match5
            continue
        end

%         append row in T2 to T1
        T1{tt1,{'County_Name', 'City_Name', 'Town_Name', ....
            'CrashTime', 'SecondaryLocation', 'RouteName', ....
            'PostalCityName'}} = ....
            table2cell( T2(tt2,{'County_Name', 'City_Name', ....
            'Town_Name', 'CrashTime', 'SecondaryLocation', ....
            'RouteName', 'PostalCityName'}) );
        augmented(tt1) = true;
%         break % assume unique matching
    end
end

fprintf('%s',repmat(sprintf('\b'),1,length('Progress:        ')))
fprintf('Matching finished at %s \nTotalling %d matches. \n', ....
    datestr(datetime('now')), sum(augmented))
```

---

Edit: With newly uploaded data set by OP, more cases are covered.

- Road crossings such as `'GEORGETOWN PIKE/CENTRILLION DR'` should be matched with either `'GEORGETOWN PIKE'` or `'CENTRILLION DR'`.
- Interstate names like `'I95'` has numerics in its name that should be differentiated from street numbers.
- Interstate names sometimes contains detailed location which should be ignored. (And look at other information)

Added progress display.

---

Edit: I forgot to use `augmented` record to speed things up. Also, added debugging part at the end in order to see which conditions are not met during a match.

---

Here is a solution using the `table` class in Matlab. Since it's a pretty new feature, programming in different versions of Matlab may vary. I'm using R2015b.

Key points:

1. For each row in Dataset 2, find match through all rows in Dataset 1.
2. If any content of the record ***mismatches***, skip. Otherwise,
   consider them to belong to the same incident.
3. Attach additional content in Dataset 2 to 1.

---

Example code with comments:

```
(obsolete)
```

---

I got this message from Matlab

> Warning: Variable names were modified to make them valid MATLAB
>   identifiers.

So you may have to change the column names in the tables to your desire.

---

These are the original datasets imported from your csv files

```
(obsolete)
```

Example output:

```
(obsolete)
```

New data set and output:

```
>> T1

T1 = 

    IncidentDate                   AddressStreet                   AddressCityIncident    AddressCountyIncident    AddressState    IncidentPostalCode    DispatchNotified      UnitNotified  
    ____________    ___________________________________________    ___________________    _____________________    ____________    __________________    ________________    ________________

    '1/1/2014'      'BURKE LAKE RD/BURKE RD'                       'BURKE'                'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22015                 '1/1/2014 1:33'     '1/1/2014 1:33' 
    '1/1/2014'      'BURKE LAKE RD/BURKE RD'                       'BURKE'                'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22015                 '1/1/2014 1:33'     '1/1/2014 1:33' 
    '1/1/2014'      'I95 SB TO OLD KEENE MILL RD'                  'SPRINGFIELD'          'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22150                 '1/1/2014 2:00'     '1/1/2014 2:00' 
    '1/1/2014'      'SYDENSTRICKER RD/OLD KEENE MILL RD'           'BURKE'                'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22015                 '1/1/2014 4:54'     '1/1/2014 4:54' 
    '1/1/2014'      'RT28 SB THRU RAMP/RT28 SB RAMP TO RT50 WB'    'CHANTILLY'            'Fairfax County'         'VA'            20151                 '1/1/2014 12:28'    '1/1/2014 12:28'
    '1/1/2014'      '11700 SWARTS DR'                              'FAIRFAX'              'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22030                 '1/1/2014 13:07'    '1/1/2014 13:07'
    '1/1/2014'      '11700 SWARTS DR'                              'FAIRFAX'              'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22030                 '1/1/2014 13:07'    '1/1/2014 13:07'
    '1/1/2014'      'CENTREVILLE RD/BRADENTON DR'                  'CENTREVILLE'          'Fairfax County'         'VA'            20121                 '1/1/2014 13:41'    '1/1/2014 13:41'
    '1/1/2014'      'GEORGETOWN PIKE/CENTRILLION DR'               'MCLEAN'               'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22102                 '1/1/2014 16:45'    '1/1/2014 16:45'
    '1/1/2014'      'GEORGETOWN PIKE/CENTRILLION DR'               'MCLEAN'               'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22102                 '1/1/2014 16:42'    '1/1/2014 16:42'
    '1/1/2014'      '8526 GEORGETOWN PIKE'                         'MCLEAN'               'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22102                 '1/1/2014 16:49'    '1/1/2014 16:49'
    '1/1/2014'      'OX RD/BRADDOCK RD'                            'FAIRFAX'              'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22032                 '1/1/2014 22:32'    '1/1/2014 22:32'

>> T2

T2 = 

    CrashDate       County_Name       City_Name    Town_Name    CrashTime        SecondaryLocation              RouteName         PostalCityName
    __________    ________________    _________    _________    _________    __________________________    ___________________    ______________

    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '6:35'       ''                            'I95'                  'LORTON'      
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '5:19'       ''                            'I95 RAMP'             'SPRINGFIELD' 
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '10:23'      ''                            'I495'                 'ANNANDALE'   
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '2:08'       ''                            'BUILDERS RD'          'HERNDON'     
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '16:42'      ''                            'GEORGETOWN PIKE'      'MCLEAN'      
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '20:55'      'LEESBURG PIKE'               'WILSON BLVD'          'FALLS CHURCH'
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '4:54'       ''                            'SYDENSTRICKER RD'     'BURKE'       
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '2:34'       'BEACON HILL RD'              'RICHMOND HWY'         'ALEXANDRIA'  
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '2:00'       ''                            'COAT RIDGE RD'        'HERNDON'     
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '13:17'      ''                            'OLD KEENE MILL RD'    'BURKE'       
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '5:19'       'MCLEAREN RD'                 'CENTREVILLE RD'       'HERNDON'     
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '21:48'      'VIRGINIA CENTER BLVD'        'VADEN DR'             'VIENNA'      
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '19:59'      'FAIRFAX COUNTY PKWY RAMP'    'LEE HWY RAMP'         'FAIRFAX'     
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '2:36'       ''                            'I95'                  'SPRINGFIELD' 
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '20:36'      'MOUNT GILEAD RD'             'BRADDOCK RD'          'CENTREVILLE' 
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '1:46'       ''                            'I95'                  'LORTON'      
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '18:45'      ''                            'I495'                 'HAMPTON'     
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '13:40'      'BRADENTON DR'                'CENTREVILLE RD'       'CENTREVILLE' 
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '17:24'      'SHREVE HILL RD'              'IDYLWOOD RD'          'DUNN LORING' 
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '17:46'      'SACRAMENTO DR'               'RICHMOND HWY'         'ALEXANDRIA'  
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '1:40'       ''                            'WINBOURNE RD'         'BURKE'       
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '1:33'       ''                            'BURKE LAKE RD'        'BURKE'       
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '15:44'      'TELEGRAPH RD'                'FRANCONIA RD'         'ALEXANDRIA'  
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '22:19'      'OX RD'                       'BRADDOCK RD'          'FAIRFAX'     
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '12:27'      ''                            'SULLY RD'             'HERNDON'     
    '1/1/2014'    'Fairfax County'    NaN          NaN          '11:25'      'MONUMENT DR'                 'LEE HWY'              'FAIRFAX'     



T1 = 

    IncidentDate                   AddressStreet                   AddressCityIncident    AddressCountyIncident    AddressState    IncidentPostalCode    DispatchNotified      UnitNotified        County_Name       City_Name    Town_Name    CrashTime    SecondaryLocation        RouteName         PostalCityName
    ____________    ___________________________________________    ___________________    _____________________    ____________    __________________    ________________    ________________    ________________    _________    _________    _________    _________________    __________________    ______________

    '1/1/2014'      'BURKE LAKE RD/BURKE RD'                       'BURKE'                'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22015                 '1/1/2014 1:33'     '1/1/2014 1:33'     'Fairfax County'    [NaN]        [NaN]        '1:33'       ''                   'BURKE LAKE RD'       'BURKE'       
    '1/1/2014'      'BURKE LAKE RD/BURKE RD'                       'BURKE'                'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22015                 '1/1/2014 1:33'     '1/1/2014 1:33'     'Fairfax County'    [NaN]        [NaN]        '1:33'       ''                   'BURKE LAKE RD'       'BURKE'       
    '1/1/2014'      'I95 SB TO OLD KEENE MILL RD'                  'SPRINGFIELD'          'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22150                 '1/1/2014 2:00'     '1/1/2014 2:00'     ''                  ''           ''           ''           ''                   ''                    ''            
    '1/1/2014'      'SYDENSTRICKER RD/OLD KEENE MILL RD'           'BURKE'                'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22015                 '1/1/2014 4:54'     '1/1/2014 4:54'     'Fairfax County'    [NaN]        [NaN]        '4:54'       ''                   'SYDENSTRICKER RD'    'BURKE'       
    '1/1/2014'      'RT28 SB THRU RAMP/RT28 SB RAMP TO RT50 WB'    'CHANTILLY'            'Fairfax County'         'VA'            20151                 '1/1/2014 12:28'    '1/1/2014 12:28'    ''                  ''           ''           ''           ''                   ''                    ''            
    '1/1/2014'      '11700 SWARTS DR'                              'FAIRFAX'              'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22030                 '1/1/2014 13:07'    '1/1/2014 13:07'    ''                  ''           ''           ''           ''                   ''                    ''            
    '1/1/2014'      '11700 SWARTS DR'                              'FAIRFAX'              'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22030                 '1/1/2014 13:07'    '1/1/2014 13:07'    ''                  ''           ''           ''           ''                   ''                    ''            
    '1/1/2014'      'CENTREVILLE RD/BRADENTON DR'                  'CENTREVILLE'          'Fairfax County'         'VA'            20121                 '1/1/2014 13:41'    '1/1/2014 13:41'    'Fairfax County'    [NaN]        [NaN]        '13:40'      'BRADENTON DR'       'CENTREVILLE RD'      'CENTREVILLE' 
    '1/1/2014'      'GEORGETOWN PIKE/CENTRILLION DR'               'MCLEAN'               'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22102                 '1/1/2014 16:45'    '1/1/2014 16:45'    'Fairfax County'    [NaN]        [NaN]        '16:42'      ''                   'GEORGETOWN PIKE'     'MCLEAN'      
    '1/1/2014'      'GEORGETOWN PIKE/CENTRILLION DR'               'MCLEAN'               'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22102                 '1/1/2014 16:42'    '1/1/2014 16:42'    'Fairfax County'    [NaN]        [NaN]        '16:42'      ''                   'GEORGETOWN PIKE'     'MCLEAN'      
    '1/1/2014'      '8526 GEORGETOWN PIKE'                         'MCLEAN'               'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22102                 '1/1/2014 16:49'    '1/1/2014 16:49'    'Fairfax County'    [NaN]        [NaN]        '16:42'      ''                   'GEORGETOWN PIKE'     'MCLEAN'      
    '1/1/2014'      'OX RD/BRADDOCK RD'                            'FAIRFAX'              'Fairfax County'         'VA'            22032                 '1/1/2014 22:32'    '1/1/2014 22:32'    'Fairfax County'    [NaN]        [NaN]        '22:19'      'OX RD'              'BRADDOCK RD'         'FAIRFAX'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139042/discussion-on-answer-by-yvon-merging-2-datasets-with-multiple-variables-cannot).